# How to implement a hierarchical structure in a Qt model using MV?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I recently started learning Qt and am studying models.

I have the following hierarchical model.

```
struct group{
 QList<sample> samples;
QString name;
}

struct sample{
QString name;
}
```

There are groups - a list of groups. Each group has several samples. This completes the hierarchy.

The sample has no children, and the group has no parent.

But this hierarchy has really caused me problems and I cannot implement it using qt mv QAbstractItemModel to display it like TreeView.

In the tree, as a root - I need to display the name of the group, and as a leaf - a specific selection of a particular group.

Comment: I'd recommend the [Model/View Tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html) of the Qt online doc. in this case.

Comment: It's just hard to perceive how such a hierarchy can be built in ct. And for this I wanted to get an example like this According to my guesses, you cannot use a tree view here, but you need to write your own widget and view?

Comment: _but you need to write your own widget and view_ IMHO, it's the subject of the model but not of the view. However, if all this model/view stuff is still too complicated, why don't you use a [QWidgetTree](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#details)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store pointers to your `group` and `sample` objects in the `QModelIndex::internalPointer`

Adapting [this example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html), you get

```
class GroupModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit GroupModel(QList<group> groups, QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                        int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    QModelIndex index(int row, int column,
                      const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;

private:

    QList<group> groups;
};

GroupModel::GroupModel(QList<group> groups, QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractItemModel(parent), groups(groups)
{
}

QModelIndex GroupModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (!hasIndex(row, column, parent))
        return QModelIndex();

    if (!parent.isValid())
        return createIndex(row, column, &groups[row]);
    if (group * g = static_cast<group *>(parent.internalPointer()))
        return createIndex(row, column, &g->samples[row]);
    return QModelIndex();
}

QModelIndex GroupModel::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QModelIndex();

    void * p = index.internalPointer();

    for (int i = 0; i < groups.count; ++i) 
    {
        if (p == &groups[i]) return QModelIndex();
        for (auto & s : groups[i]->samples)
        {
            if (p == &s) return createIndex(i, 0, &groups[i]);
        }
    }

    return QModelIndex();
}

int GroupModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.column() > 0)
        return 0;
    else if (!parent.isValid())
        return groups.count()
    else if (group * g = static_cast<group *>(parent.internalPointer()))
        return g->samples.count();
}

int GroupModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return 1;
}

QVariant GroupModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant();

    if (!index.parent().isValid())
        return static_cast<group *>(index.internalPointer())->name;

    return static_cast<sample *>(index.internalPointer())->name;
}

QVariant GroupModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                               int role) const
{
    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
        return "Name";

    return QVariant();
}
```

Comment: What is the variable "group". For example (
    if (sample *childItem = &group->samples[row]))

Comment: @RdEErAqUa? I don't have that anywhere. `group * g` is declared the line above `return createIndex(row, column, &g->samples[row]);`

Comment: In function `if(parent.column > 0) return 0;`as I understand it, this is a check for whether the element is sample. If true, then return 0 child. But all the elements have .column = 0. And it turns out that in the next check `se if (group * g = static_cast<group *>(parent.internalPointer()))` always pass. And `return g->samples.count();` And it can return an undefined value, and it turns out that it is as if the sample has children. What's the best way to fix this error?

Comment: No, the `column > 0` check is because you only have a column at index 0